# Tab in show Customer information Grid in Custom module for Magento 2.1.x

Tags: grid, magento-2.1.4

Tab in show Customer information Grid in Custom module for Magento2.1.4
[image]
How to do???

Comment: can you explain your question?

Comment: Need Tab in Grid..with Radio button so only one Product select..

Comment: its difficult to understand, could you please post a snap of your requirement.

Comment: Please check..updated snap.